# Inserting data using nhibernate

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, nhibernate

I'm trying to insert a record using nhibernate. here's the error i'm getting(or rather the message being displayed by my test console app. the second part with error header is the exception caught):

```
 NHibernate.GuitarStore assembly initialized.
NHibernate: INSERT INTO INVENTORY (TYPEID, BUILDER, MODEL, QOH, COST, PRICE,RECEIVED)    
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();@p0 = 1 [Type:Int32 (0)], @p1 = 'Test Builder 2' [Type: String (4000)], @p2 = 'Test Model 2' [Type: String (4000)], @p3 = 9 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p4 = 2000 [Type: Decimal (0)], @p5 = 200 [Type: Decimal (0)], @p6 = 7/19/2013 7:35:51 PM [Type: DateTime (0)]

***** ERROR *****
could not insert: [NHibernate.GuitarStore.Common.Inventory][SQL: INSERT INTO INVENTORY (TYPEID, BUILDER, MODEL, QOH, COST, PRICE, RECEIVED) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?); select COPE_IDENTITY()] - InnerExcepetion: Operand type clash: int is incompatible with image
```

Looking at the insert SQL generated it seems to me that the values match their respective types. I dont know which int is incompatible with image as the error says.

PS: i dont have any column in my db of type image

Edit: here's the schema of inventory:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inventory](builder] [varchar](50) NULL, [model] [varchar](50) NULL,
[qoh] [image] NOT NULL,
[cost] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[price] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[received] [datetime] NULL,
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[typeid] [int] NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_Inventory_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON  PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Can you please post the schema for the table "INVENTORY"?

Comment: thanks @BillGregg i've edited with the schema pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because column QOH is of type Image, and you are trying to insert an integer (9) into that column.

Comment: Thanks bro...i never meant to make qoh image and i couldnt believe it *face covered*

Comment: It happens.  When debugging stuff, it helps to challenge and confirm EVERYTHING.  :)